# How to compare a DB value to another DB value in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to compare two values of the database. Is it possible to do so with the "where" method? For example, the "tnx_time" would be one DB value and the "value(duration)" the other one. But I cannot now access the DB values on the 3rd field of the "where" function.

Does anybody know how to fix that?

```
$trnxs =  Transaction::where('tnx_time', '<',  date("Y-m-d", strtotime( value(duration) )) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback in your "where" clause to create a subquery, would be something like this (might need some changing)

```
$trnxs = Transaction::where('tnx_time', '<', function ($query) {
    $query->selectRaw('date("Y-m-d", strtotime(value(duration)))');
})->get();
```